# ¿Cómo calcular valores de una tabla de forma dinámica con javaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando un sistema para registrar albaranes de compra y necesito calcular el precio total de un producto a partir de su cantidad y su precio unitario.

Hasta ahora lo que he conseguido es recuperar los valores de cantidad y precio unitario, calcular los precios totales y guardarlos en un array, pero no sé como mostrar cada valor de array en la columna Total price.

¿Como puedo mostrar el precio total calculado en la fila que le corresponde usando javaScript/jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cantidades;
    var precios;
    var preciosTotal;
    
    
    $(".cantidad").change(function(){
        var valorCantidades = new Array();
        var valorPrecios = new Array();
        var valorPreciosTotales= new Array();
        
        cantidades=$(".cantidad");
        precios=$(".precio");
        preciosTotal=$(".precioTotal");
        
        
        for(var i=0;i<cantidades.length;i++){
            valorCantidades.push($(cantidades[i]).val());            
        }
        
        for(var i=0;i<precios.length;i++){
            valorPrecios.push($(precios[i]).val());
        }
        
        for(var i=0;i<precios.length;i++){
            valorPreciosTotales.push(valorCantidades[i]*valorPrecios[i]);
        }        
        
    });
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Product code</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                <th scope="col">Unit price</th>
                                <th scope="col">Total price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                                    <td>Bike</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control cantidad" value="0"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control precio" value="0"></td>
                                    <td class="precioTotal"></td>
                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                                    <td>Football ball</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control cantidad" value="0"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control precio" value="0"></td>
                                    <td class="precioTotal"></td>
                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                                    <td>Football shirt</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control cantidad" value="0"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control precio" value="0"></td>
                                    <td class="precioTotal"></td>
                                </tr>
                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2>Total:</h2>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="../../JS/prueba.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Peter. Dices que no lo has conseguido pero tampoco veo codigo que muestre los intentos. Ahora estás aplicando el evento onchange sobre el elemento por ID. El ID es algo unico por lo que has de cambiar la manera a la que accedes a cada campo. yo usaría un atributo como class. Intenta algo y despues pulsa en [edit] para explicar tus problemas concretos siguiendo [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Peter, tal y como indica lois6b el id debe ser único cambia id por class y utiliza la función `getElementsByClassName` con ello podrás obtener todos los input con las clases indicadas. Para obtener estos input simplemente haz $(document).getElementsByClassName e ir recorriendo y sumando sus value

Answer (score 0):

Realmente lo correcto sería identificar la inequívocamente la tabla y definir todos los campos para reunir todos los valores en un solo objeto, ya que así hay el riesgo de perder la correlación de los índices de los distintos arrays. Pero un parche desesperado sería:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function actualizarTabla() {
        var cantidades = [];
        var precios = [];
        var preciosTotal = [];

        var total = 0;
        $(".table tbody > tr").each(function(index) {
            var cantidad = Number($(this).find('.cantidad').val());
            cantidades.push(cantidad);

            var precio = Number($(this).find('.precio').val());
            precios.push(precio);

            var total_unitario = cantidad * precio;
            preciosTotal.push(total_unitario);
            $(this).find('.precioTotal').text(total_unitario+' €');
            total += total_unitario;
        });
        $("h2").text('Total: '+total+' €');
    }

    actualizarTabla();

    $(".table").on('change', function() {
        actualizarTabla();
    });

});
</script>
```